# Unable to stop setInterval from buttons or after timer counts down javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I've been working on a timer that can be paused if they press the stop button or the reset button as well as stopping after the countdown has reaches $minLeft=0 $secLeft = 0. I haven't done a timer before but from what I've learned on stackoverflow it seems that setInterval would be the best option but I'm not opposed to doing a repeating setTimeout. The timer is going well except I can't pause it in any of the options. After trying many different directions this is my best guess to being close but it is still not working. Does anyone see what I'm doing incorrectly. You can check it out on codepen if it is easier [Pomodoro Clock](http://codepen.io/RawleJuglal/pen/JGPXgy)

```js
function getId(){
  var $buttonID = $(event.target.id).selector;
  console.log($buttonID);
  var initialize= 0,intervalId;
  if($buttonID == "startButton")
    {
      if(initialize == 0)
        {
          var intialTime = Number($('#sesStartTime').text());
          updateCountdown(intialTime, 0);
          initialize = 1;
          $('#startButton').attr("id", "stopButton").text("Stop");
          intervalId = startTimer();
        }
      else
        {
          intervalId = startTimer();
        }
    }
  else if($buttonID == "resetButton")
    {
      stopTimer(intervalId);
      var prevTime = Number($('#sesStartTime').text());
      updateCountdown(prevTime, 0);
    }
  else if($buttonID == "stopButton")
    {
      $('#stopButton').attr("id", "startButton").text("Start");
      stopTimer(intervalId);
    } 
  else
    {
      console.log("Entered else statement for gatherTimeInfo");
      gatherTimeInfo($buttonID);
    }
  
}

function startTimer(){
  setInterval(checkFinish,1000);
}

function stopTimer(timer){
  clearInterval(timer);
  
}

function checkFinish (timer){
  var $minLeft = Number($('#countdownClock span:first-child').text())
  var $secLeft = Number($('#countdownClock span:nth-child(2)').text());
  console.log("This is minLeft: " + $minLeft + " and this is secLeft: " + $secLeft);
  
  if($minLeft ==0 && $secLeft == 0)
    {
      stopTimer(timer);
      console.log("I've finished the alert loop"); 
    }
  else
    {
      if($secLeft == 0 && $minLeft >=1)
        {
          console.log("Still more than a minute to go");
          $minLeft--;
          $secLeft = 59
          updateCountdown($minLeft, $secLeft);
        }
      else if($secLeft > 0 && $minLeft >=1)
        {
          console.log("Still more than a minute to go");
          $secLeft--;
          updateCountdown($minLeft, $secLeft);
        }
      else
        {
          console.log("Less than a minute");
          $secLeft--;
          updateCountdown($minLeft, $secLeft);
        }
    }
}

$( "button" ).click(function() {
  getId();
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sessionBox">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <h4 class="text-center">Session Time</h4>
                        </div><!--End of col-md-12-->
                      </div><!--End of row-->
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                           <button id="sesMinus" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></button>
                        </div><!--End of col-md-4-->
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                           <p id="sesStartTime" class="text-center">5</p>
                        </div><!--End of col-md-4-->
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <button id="sesPlus" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>
                        </div><!--End of col-md-4-->
                      </div><!--End of row-->
                    </div><!--End of sessionBox-->
<div id="timerBox">
   <h3 id="currentPeriod" class="text-center">Session</h3>
   <p id="countdownClock" class="text-center"><span>00</span> : <span>00</span></p>
</div><!--End of timerBox-->


<div id="interfaceBox">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div id="startButtonDiv">
                          <p class="text-center"><button id="startButton" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Start</button></p>
                        </div><!--End of startButton-->
                      </div><!--End of col-md-6-->
                    </div><!--End of row-->    
                  </div><!--End of col-md-6-->
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div id="resetButtonDiv">
                          <p class="text-center"><button id="resetButton"  class="btn btn-default btn-block">Reset</button></p>
                        </div><!--End of resetButton-->
                      </div><!--End of col-md-6-->
                    </div><!--End of row--> 
                  </div><!--End of col-md-6-->
                </div><!--End of row-->
              </div><!--End of interfaceBox-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable where timer reference is stored and return that reference from startTimer method

```
var intervalId;

function startTimer(){
  return setInterval(checkFinish,1000);
}
```

Comment: Like the previous comment I added return to the startTimer function but also tried as you suggested at the top of the js file adding var timer = startTimer(). The clock now starts running no matter what button is pushed (I had others on the page that were not relevant so I left out of the snippet) and it also will not stop the timer when I press stop, reset or let the timer run down to zero. I'll also ask the same as the previous response, do I have something wrong in the buttons calling stopTimer() which I thought would then run clearInterval(timer) ?

Comment: @RawleJuglal What I meant was that you need to return the timer object. Rather than calling it at top, simply make the 'intervalId' global.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. Literally hours I spent on just that one part before I finally gave in. Seriously, thanks for taking the time to look at it!

Answer (score 0):

You don't return value from `startTimer()` function so, intervalId is left undefined when you call `intervalId = startTimer();`

Comment: I added the return in the setTimer function, but still if I press stop, reset, or let the countdown run to 0 which all options are set to call stopTimer(intervalId) it doesn't stop the countdown. I am calling this wrong?